# QT dont play sound if its already playing?

Tags: qt

How can I make sure that a sound does not start to play if another one is already playing?

Im using the following code to play sounds:

```
void MainWindow::displayNotification(QString message)
{    
    // Play sound notification
    QSound *sound = new QSound("://2_1.wav", this);
    sound->play();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a pointer to the playing QSound in your MainWindow, then check if it has finished with the [isFinished](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsound.html#isFinished) function.

```
void MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QString audiofile("://2_1.wav");
    m_pSound = new QSound(audiofile, this);
    if(!m_pSound)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to initialise sound file: " << audiofile;
    }
}

void MainWindow::displayNotification(QString message)
{    
    if(!m_pSound) // check m_pSound is initialised
        return;

    // check if sound is playing
    if(!m_pSound->isFinished)
        return;

    // Play sound notification        
    m_pSound->play();
}
```

Note that m_pSound is now declared as a member variable of MainWindow.

Comment: It crashes on this line `if(!m_pSound->isFinished)` I've declared it in my .h like this: `QSound *m_pSound;` Any ideas?

Comment: You need to initialise the m_pSound ptr and then check it is valid before dereferencing the pointer; see the change in code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

the class "QSound" has the method "isFinished()" for that reason.

```
if(m_pSound->isFinished())
    //play
else
    //wait
```